# How to create a graph like bloomberg terminal from Wrold Bank API data

Tags: php, json, data-visualization, bloomberg

I have a app written using PHP, I wanted to display the data coming from world bank api

```
http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/<Product Name>?date=2000M01:2020M12&per_page=1000&format=json.
```

here data is returned based on the product name and date, If you pass the  = PALM_OIL, You can able to see the data in JSON

Is there any tool available to create a graph just like bloomberg terminal, which is shown below

[image]